# PrimgNg Tree, fill filter input when using _filter method

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNg with my Angular 12 project and recently started using a Tree component
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tree

The problem is the filter input not being filled when I use the _filter() method although the filter works well but the filter input is empty. This causes a problem, in case that I want to cancel the filtering, I have to type anything in the filter input and clear it again plus the user might not recognize that the tree is filtered.
Is there any solution or workaround to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accessed the input element by its class name and set the value manually after applying the filter.

`const elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.p-tree-filter'); elements[0].value = this.filterValue;`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can access the value:

Step1: Declare variable like this

```
nativeElement: HTMLElement;
constructor(
    element: ElementRef
) {
    this.nativeElement = element.nativeElement;
}
```

Step 2: Get the value of filter textbox of p-tree like this

```
let nodes = this.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.p-tree-filter');
    nodes.forEach((node: any, i) => {
        if (i == 0) {
            console.log(node.value);
        }
    });
```